# Conflict with PrimeNg p-grid & bootstrap Padding usage

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8, primeng, ngx-bootstrap

I've recently upgraded my angular project from 5 to 8. My project was also having a dependency on bootstrap v4 (Since I've used ngx-bootstrap). I had to upgrade the primeNg from 5.x.x to v9.2Lts.

Now that the primeNg has changed it's flex grid implementation from ui-g to p-g, similarly the responsive usage of u- to p- . this p- class is common in both the frameworks ... which is conflicting the UI.

Comment: And? What is the point of this question, I can't seem to understand.